# Editing .json files in a zip folder, without unzipping

Tags: json, zip, relative-path

I am in the process of uploading a huge number of tests for my school (I am a computer science teacher). These come in the form of .h5p files. I need to parse information into the .h5p files from .txt documents, ready for uploading to Moodle courses. To do this, I have built an app to push the data from .txt files into the .json files in the .h5p file.

The problem is that my app converts the h5p to a zip, unzips it and then parses the information, rezips and then changes the extension again to h5p. Would you mind watching this video https://youtu.be/FTyQddAcWa8 and letting me know how I might be able to edit the .json files and then rezip ready for uploading to the Moodle courses? The files throw up errors once unzipped and then zipped again.

I think the unzipping process is altering the relative links.

Bottom line is, these tests are critical in my school of 1,274 children mitigating the impact of COVID-19 lockdown.

Comment: Thank you halfer. I really appreciate your help. 

Comment: OK. This looks like a duplicate of your previous question, so I would start by advocating that you delete that one. Normally we ask that questions are edited so they can be reopened, rather than a duplicate being created. Nevertheless, I will try to add some advice below.

Comment: For readers, and to summarise a shared understanding of the problem, your video appears to show you downloading a .h5p file from a Moodle installation, and opening up a JSON file. Your editor complains that the JSON file is invalid (though I do not know if that assessment is true) and it looks like you are trying to fix something in that file. You then re-zip it, and try to upload it into Moodle, whereupon Moodle collapses in a shower of fairly incomprehensible errors.

Comment: Makyen's advice on the other question was sound - an external video is not an ideal way to show the problem, since it is our experience that video links are deleted in due course. Questions on Stack Overflow are intended to live for essentially forever, for the purpose of helping many future developers. Videos are, believe it or not, time consuming to watch - readers will generally give ten seconds to see whether a problem is within their skillset. Whether that is right or wrong is another question, but it is what it is.

Comment: So, the Moodle importer is complaining about internal folder names within the zip file. This seems unreasonable, since the zip file is obtained from a Moodle installation and it seems to have internal folders. In the same error it explains valid extensions, which is unrelated to folder names, so my first thought is that the importer is not particularly well tested.

Comment: My other guess is that it is objecting to spaces in the spaces in `multiple-choice-713(1) Copy`. That is generally permitted in the zip specification, but perhaps Moodle disallows it. I would therefore suggest trying this process again, but only use a zip file without spaces in the zip file name.

Comment: Finally, if your script/program that you are using might be creating the problem that you are seeing, then (obviously) readers will need to see the code of that program (or the relevant bit of it) in order to help.

Comment: Halfer, you are literally my hero!!!

Comment: I think you are right about the spaces

Comment: I will adjust the script and let you know how I get on

Comment: Wish I could buy you a beer , irrespective of outcome. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Do let me know how you get on. If the space thing does not fix it, then I suggest editing the post to include information about your script. if the space thing does fix it, I would suggest raising a bug against Moodle (or whatever system reads/writes these .h5p files) since the error is actively misleading (and probably is not even an error).

Answer (score 0):

The unzipping process is not the problem, but the zipping is.

When you upload the file, H5P is complaining because it expects some flags to be set when zipping:

- -D   do not add directory entries
- -X   eXclude eXtra file attributes

I assume that at some point your script is calling zip. That call would need to pass the correct flags. On a command line, you'd use

```
zip -rDX myNewFile.h5p *
```

to pack all files in the current directory into a valid H5P content file named myNewFile.h5p. Just "translate" that into your script.